# How to identify if there was syncpoint issued

Tags: db2, cobol, cics

I'm working on COBOL cics program,the program has multiple syncpoint and executed on different scenarios.

I wanted to perform some logic if any point of time under this cics task syncpoint issued or not.

Pls help in advise if there any way around or keywords to check the same.

Comment: Modify the COBOL to add a DISPLAY before each syncpoint.  Run the code.

Comment: I understand but Our new code works based on end of uow/task/syncpoint issued by cics. If there was syncpoint issued by program itself and that too only for specific scenario then it's logging duplicate records to the log. Wanted to know cics reserved keywords to check if there was syncpoint issued.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/search/implicit%20syncpoint?scope=SSGMCP_6.1.0) an implicit syncpoint is issued for...

- EXEC CICS CREATE TERMINAL
- EXEC CICS CREATE CONNECTION COMPLETE
- EXEC CICS DISCARD CONNECTION
- EXEC CICS DISCARD TERMINAL
- EXEC CICS RETURN at the highest level
- a DL/I program specification block (PSB) termination (TERM) call or command
- EXEC CICS DISCARD TDQUEUE
- EXEC CICS CSD DISCONNECT
- EXEC CICS CSD UNLOCK
- EXEC CICS CSD APPEND
- EXEC CICS CSD REMOVE
- EXEC CICS CSD RENAME
- EXEC CICS CSD LOCK
- EXEC CICS CSD DELETE
- EXEC CICS CSD ADD
- EXEC CICS CSD INSTALL
- EXEC CICS CSD DEFINE
- EXEC CICS CSD ALTER
- EXEC CICS CSD COPY
- EXEC CICS CSD USERDEFINE
- EXEC CICS CREATE PROCESSTYPE
- EXEC CICS CREATE DUMPCODE
- EXEC CICS CREATE PIPELINE
- EXEC CICS CREATE DUMPTEMPLATE
- EXEC CICS CREATE PARTNER
- EXEC CICS CREATE TRANCLASS
- EXEC CICS CREATE JOURNALMODEL
- EXEC CICS CREATE MAPSET
- EXEC CICS CREATE ENQMODEL
- EXEC CICS CREATE PROCESSTYPE
- EXEC CICS CREATE PARTITIONSET
- EXEC CICS CREATE TSMODEL
- EXEC CICS CREATE PROFILE
- EXEC CICS CREATE DB2TRAN
- EXEC CICS CREATE DB2ENTRY
- EXEC CICS CREATE TRANSACTION
- EXEC CICS CREATE TDQUEUE
- EXEC CICS CREATE TYPETERM
- Distributed Program Link calls specifying SYNCONRETURN

...and explicitly through an EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT.

Comment: when explicitly issued using Exec cics syncpoint, is there any flag to be set to denote syncpoint issued? Based on this flag, i need to perform some logic and this flag should not be cleared until end uof.

Comment: No.  I think you're looking for a user exit that gets control during syncpoint processing.

Comment: I may be missunderstanding what you want, but what hinders you to set a flag in your code after the `EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT`? If the `EXEC` statement succeeds, a syncpoint has been taken and your program continues with the next statement (setting a flag). If an error occurs, the program will not gain back control, I would say.

Comment: Yes that would work and was thinking the same for last resort but this requires significant testing than cics supplied syntax for syncpoint status.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that a SYNCPOINT ^should^ be null and void logically.  If your program is depending on knowing when a SYNCPOINT happens for any reason, it is likely to fail frequently in production under any sort of load.

Rather than trying to identify when a SYNCPOINT happens, you should be looking for ways to remove that (perceived) dependency from your code.  You will be better off in the end not trying to micromanage all the transaction partners and just letting the platform do its job.